# Google doc adding bullets or number lists to already existing lines

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs

I have few lines in my google doc such as

```
example
a new one
a new bie
a pie
all others
```

Now when I select all lines and apply bullet or numbering to the list above, all elements separated by new line will not be get bullets or numbers, only the first item will get it. So o/p looks like

```
1. example
a new one
a new bie
a pie
all others
```

and expected o/p for me is

```
1. example
2. a new one
3. a new bie
4. a pie
5. all others
```

There is one method to do this which is hit enter from second line onward and then hit delete. But its complexity is more (O(n) linear lol). Is there any way to do this in one instruction just by selecting list at once an applying bullet or numbering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this problem you have is due to the use of Shift+Enter (instead of Enter) to make a new line. When using Shift+Enter, Word and Google Doc will see the new line as the same paragraph, thus keep the same bullet number, style etc.

**Solution**: try copy the original text to Notepad or Notepad ++ and then copy it back to Doc. Then try apply the Bullet Numbering. It works for me.

Note:
If it does not work, there are also another fix using Notepad ++ but I need the original text to try, because I can not reproduce the same error, where the above solution cannot fix

Comment: yes that solves, I used Ubuntu's internal "text editor" instead of notepad++ and it works, thanks